The directly pasted XPATH of a link into selenium is leading to another link
I am automating the login and profile completion of a Linkden profile. I have been able to get to the home page and past the login page. I am trying to go to the profile page by simulating the click of the link. In order to do this I used the XPATH I directly copied from the inspect page but instead of going to the profile page it is going to a different page. I am not doing this by id as I wish for this code to work for anyone who plugs their login information in.
Here is the code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import json


with open('information.json', 'r') as file:
    bio_data = json.load(file)


username = ''
password = ''
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')  # for headless mode
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Login -------------------------------------------------
try:
    driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')
    username_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')
    username_field.send_keys(username)

    password_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password')
    password_field.send_keys(password)

    password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    time.sleep(5)

# Posting pages -----------------------------------------

    link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/a')
    link.click()


finally:
    driver.quit()





Try to first celar cookies and simulate your workflow by hand from scratch. Probably the same dialog will appear. Try to handle that first.
Be aware that LinkedIn will block your account if it recognizes automation

How could avoid automation detection by LinkedIn

Be smarter. So no actual tips

First a couple comments on your code:

time.sleep() is inefficient and unreliable, in most cases it's recommended to use WebDriverWait
Using full path like this is unreadable, unreliable (and ugly) (By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/a'). Searching by class name, id, etc.. is preferred.

Now back to your code, this single line would do what you need. And don't forget to import the right classes. Also time.sleep() in your example can be removed.
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="ember-view block"]'))).click()


After doing that I attempted to use a similarly structured line to click on the add profile section button, but that is returning a error. Here is the line
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@text()="Add profile section"]'))).click() What am I doing wrong here? And where can I find a good source so I can appropriately use XPATH.

There are a few issues with your line: don't put @ before text(), the text you are searching is located within span tag (not within the button), and lastly, that element is covered by something else when selenium finds it.

This should resolve all the issues: first, let's find the right element to click on elem = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[span[text()="Add profile section"]]')[1]; second, we need to use key action because in my case the element is covered by the header elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).

For XPATH reference, there are many resources, for example, you could try this https://devhints.io/xpath

Try better to get the element using class name, and click it

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
